# Admob banner is blank

Tags: android, xml, admob

As the title says my Admob banner shows up but its blank, i cannot for the life of me figure this one and ive been playing around with it for a while...

Here is my main xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            ads:adUnitId="myID"
            ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

<ScrollView 
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_above="@id/adView">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
            android:background="@drawable/mybuttonbg"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/sound1"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
            android:background="@drawable/mybuttonbg"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/sound2"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button7"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button7"
            android:layout_marginTop="39dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button2"
            android:background="@drawable/mybuttonbg"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/sound4"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button6"
            android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
            android:background="@drawable/mybuttonbg"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/sound7"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button3"
            android:background="@drawable/mybuttonbg"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/sound8"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button2"
            android:background="@drawable/mybuttonbg"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/sound9"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/mybuttonbg"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/sound3"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button6"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button6"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button2"
            android:background="@drawable/mybuttonbg"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/sound10"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button10"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button9"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button9"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button6"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button8"
            android:background="@drawable/mybuttonbg"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/sound6"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/button9"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button6"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button6"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button7"
            android:background="@drawable/mybuttonbg"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/sound5"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button11"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button9"
            android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button2"
            android:background="@drawable/mybuttonbg"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/sound11"
            android:textSize="16sp" /> 

        </RelativeLayout>  
    </ScrollView>          
</RelativeLayout>
```

Manifest entry

```
<activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"/>
```

I have not implemented any java for this banner as i believe this type of banner works with just the xml entry

Answer (score 2):

Solved!

I needed to add the following to my main activity

```
    mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    mAdView.setAdListener(new ToastAdListener(this));
    mAdView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
```